# Ethereum transaction giving error 'invalid sender'

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

This is how my contract looks like -

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.8.0;


contract Calculator {
    uint public result;

    event Added(address caller, uint a, uint b, uint res);

    constructor() public {
        result = 777;
    }

    function add(uint a, uint b) public returns (uint, address) {
        result = a + b;
        emit Added(msg.sender, a, b, result);
        return (result, msg.sender);
    }
}
```

Above contract is deployed on Ropsten test net. And I am trying to invoke the `add(...)` function with a transaction. And my code looks like this -

```
const accountAddress = rtUtil.getAccountAddress();
const accountPk = Buffer.from(rtUtil.getAccountAddressPk(), "hex");
const contract = await rtUtil.getCalculatorContract();
const data = contract.methods.add(3, 74).encodeABI();

const web3 = rtUtil.getWeb3();
const taxCount = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accountAddress);

const txObject = {
   nonce: web3.utils.toHex(taxCount),
   to: rtUtil.getCalculatorContractAddress(),
   value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether')),
   gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(2100000),
   gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('6', 'gwei')),
   data: data
};

const commmon = new Common({chain: "ropsten", hardfork: "petersburg"});
const tx = Transaction.fromTxData(txObject, {commmon});
tx.sign(accountPk);

const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
const raw = web3.utils.toHex(serializedTx);
const transaction = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw);
```

And when I run the code I get error -

```
Uncaught Error: Returned error: invalid sender
Process exited with code 1
```

My Nodejs versions is `v15.1.0`

And my `package.json` dependencies are -

```
"dependencies": {
  "@ethereumjs/common": "^2.0.0",
  "@ethereumjs/tx": "^3.0.0",
  "@truffle/contract": "^4.2.30",
  "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^1.2.0",
  "web3": "^1.3.0"
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

In your txObject, you need to specific the chain id.

Add Ropsten's chain id, 3 into txObject.

```
const txObject = {
   nonce: web3.utils.toHex(taxCount),
   to: rtUtil.getCalculatorContractAddress(),
   value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether')),
   gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(2100000),
   gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('6', 'gwei')),
   data: data,
   chainId: web3.utils.toHex(3)
};
```

Comment: it work in my case, but could give more explanation  why `chainId` must be 3? Thanks

Comment: @neo its related to a simple replay attack protection, it was introduced in [EIP-155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-155) . You can also check https://chainlist.org/ for the list of chain id for each network.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `from` in your txObject:

```
const txObject = {
   from: accountAddress,
   nonce: web3.utils.toHex(taxCount),
   to: rtUtil.getCalculatorContractAddress(),
   value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether')),
   gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(2100000),
   gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('6', 'gwei')),
   data: data
};
```

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. Since the transaction is signed, so from can be retrieved from the signature. I tried with from too, but the problem persists.